# how to make a space-keeping column use css and table tag

Tags: html, css, border

What is the most elegant way to remove the up down border?

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
.noborder {
  border: none;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<br>
<table border='1' width='500'>
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th class="noborder">&nbsp;</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>BB</td>
    <td>CC</td>
    <td>DD</td>
    <td class="noborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>FF</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ur7h49y5/)

Comment: edit your fiddle. It's not the same like the picture you are showing

Comment: The border is applied on the whole table and not individual elements in your code.

Comment: i have updated the jsfiddle link, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply border for the `th` and `td` elements and not for the entire table. Setting border for the table will not be affected by the `noborder` class applied on the child elements.

[**Updated JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wyzt8ep5/)

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
.noborder {
  border: none;
  width: 50px;
}
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<br>
<table width='500'>
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th class="noborder">&nbsp;</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>BB</td>
    <td>CC</td>
    <td>DD</td>
    <td class="noborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>FF</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say specify only the borders you need.
If you don't want the top and bottom... only set the left and right border.

```
table {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

If you're trying to remove only the top and bottom of that blank column, you could try setting the border for each column separately, thus allowing the removal of the desired border.

```
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#blank-td {
  border: none /* or even 1px solid #fff */;
}
```

Just mess around with it
More info: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp